# Slow SQL Server database on a specific server

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database on a production server (Windows server 2012, Intel Xeon, 24 GB RAM).
The same database is present on my computer (Windows 10, Intel I3, 8 GB RAM).

When I'm querying the databases the response time is ~2 times longer on the production server.

The size of the databases and log files are identical.

Comment: Read "Getting Help with a Slow Query" and follow the instructions for both servers: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/

Comment: Have you compared execution plans? Are you running both from SSMS on your client pc, or remoting to the server?

Comment: The execution plans are identical, I'm running SSMS directly on each computer (not remotely)

Comment: I've run sp_Blitz I don't see any performance issue

Comment: Is your computer just faster than the production server?  The single-threaded processor and disk performance of PCs is often better than servers.

Comment: Max speed of the server's cpu : 1,60 GHz; Max speed of my cpu : 3,40 GHz. You're right!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Adam Machanic's sp_WhoIsActive while the query runs on prod?  This will show you other queries that may be taking up resources or blocking your query.

Can you confirm that the isolation level is the same for the database on the server versus your laptop?  Different isolation levels can contribute to various issues related to blocking.  You can check that by running the below in the context of the database in question.

SELECT 
[name] AS DBName
, snapshot_isolation_state_desc
, is_read_committed_snapshot_on

FROM sys.databases